# Automating javafx application using fxdriver

Tags: java, javafx

I need to automate a JavaFX application.
In order to do that I am using the fxdriver by 1C-company (https://github.com/1C-Company/FxDriver).
Recently the app I am testing removed support for 32 bit arch.
Now I am not able to run the app using the java command because the fxdiver doesnt seem to support 64 bit.
Is there a solution for this issue? can the driver be built to support 64 bit applications?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX

Comment: Yes, but first I want to see if there is a solution before I start refactoring the code from scratch to another library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product [Marathon Java Driver](https://marathontesting.com/javadriver/) which works similar.Note: I'm also a contributor for the product. Check the GitHub link [Marathon Github](https://github.com/jalian-systems/marathonv5)